# handle one-to-many relationship of domain objects in lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I had a object with following data

```
String key  
String name  
List<String> address
```

How would i create a document for lucene for above object i had to search on name and address,  i had created index on name but i also want to create index on address
for ex

```
key:1 name:sam address:lane no 1 behind la gardens  
key:1 name:sam address:near abc cross main road
```

how would i create and store index should i have to store two document with commom name and key

Answer (score 0):

```
Document temp = new Document();
temp.add(new Field("name", "sam", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
temp.add(new Field("address", "lane no 1 behind la gardens", Field.Store.YES,
                   Field.Index.ANALYZED));
indexWriter.addDocument(temp);
```

search like

```
name:sam address:gardens
```

will result in matching the above document

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want an arbitrary number of related addresses, retrievable separately, but searchable simply as:

```
address:"my address"
```

I would recommend storing addresses named whatever you like (I will use 'address1' and 'address2' here), and accumulating their text into one big old 'address' field.  Something like:

```
doc.add(new Field("key", "1", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
doc.add(new Field("name", "sam", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
doc.add(new Field("address", "lane no 1 behind la gardens near abc cross main road", Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
//Note, that you can add multiple fields with the same name, and it will effectively be merged together, as:
doc.add(new Field("address", "more address information for searching", Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
doc.add(new Field("address1", "lane no 1 behind la gardens", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));
doc.add(new Field("address2", "near abc cross main road", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));
```

Note that address is passed `Field.Store.NO` and `Field.Index.ANALYZED`, while address1 and address2 are passed `Field.Store.YES` and `Field.Index.NO`.  So you search on 'address', but never on 'address1' or 'address2', and you retrieve 'address1' and 'address2' from found documents, but never 'address'